# Solving system of ODE's using python and graphing (Chua's circuit)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ode

I'm trying to model [Chau's Circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chua%27s_circuit) in Python using `matplotlib` and `scipy`, which involves solving a system of ordinary differential equations.

This has been done [in matlab](http://www.chuacircuits.com/matlabsim.php), and I simply wanted to attempt the problem in python. The matlab code linked is a little confusing; the code on the left doesn't appear to have much relevance to solving the [system of ode's](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~chua/papers/Kennedy93b.pdf) that describe Chua's Circuit (page 3, equations (2)(3) and (4)), whilst the code on the right goes beyond that to modelling the circuit component by component.

I'm not familiar with scipy's `odeint` function so I used some of the examples from the [scipy cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/numpy_scipy_ordinary_differential_equations.html) for guidance.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot my system; why do I get a graph looking like this:

[image]

As opposed to one looking like this?

[image]

My code is attached below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def fV_1(V_1, G_a, G_b, V_b):
    if V_1 < -V_b:
        fV_1 = G_b*V_1+(G_b-G_a)*V_b
    elif -V_b <= V_1 and V_1 <=V_b:
        fV_1 = G_a*V_1
    elif V_1 > V_b:
        fV_1 = G_b*V_1+(G_a-G_b)*V_b
    else:
        print "Error!"
    return fV_1

def ChuaDerivatives(state,t):
    #unpack the state vector
    V_1 = state[0]
    V_2 = state[1]
    I_3 = state[2]

    #definition of constant parameters
    L = 0.018 #H, or 18 mH
    C_1 = 0.00000001 #F, or 10 nF
    C_2 = 0.0000001 #F, or 100 nF
    G_a = -0.000757576 #S, or -757.576 uS
    G_b = -0.000409091 #S, or -409.091 uS
    V_b = 1 #V (E)
    G = 0.000550 #S, or 550 uS VARIABLE

    #compute state derivatives
    dV_1dt = (G/C_1)*(V_2-V_1)-(1/C_1)*fV_1(V_1, G_a, G_b, V_b)
    dV_2dt = -(G/C_2)*(V_2-V_1)+(1/C_2)*I_3
    dI_3dt = -(1/L)*V_2

    #return state derivatives
    return dV_1dt, dV_2dt, dI_3dt

#set up time series
state0 = [0.1, 0.1, 0.0001]
t = np.arange(0.0, 53.0, 0.1)

#populate state information
state = odeint(ChuaDerivatives, state0, t)

# do some fancy 3D plotting
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot(state[:,0],state[:,1],state[:,2])
ax.set_xlabel('V_1')
ax.set_ylabel('V_2')
ax.set_zlabel('I_3')
plt.show()
```

Comment: My bet is that your equations are set up wrong. Even one wrong sign or an order of magnitude out for a constant can yield wildly different results. Have you triple checked they are correct? And did you check one more time after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to work it out for myself after some fiddling; I was interpreting the odeint function wrong; more careful reading of the docstring and starting from scratch to stop me following a difficult method solved it. Code below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#define universal variables
c0 = 15.6
c1 = 1.0
c2 = 28.0
m0 = -1.143
m1 = -0.714

#just a little extra, quite unimportant
def f(x):
    f = m1*x+(m0-m1)/2.0*(abs(x+1.0)-abs(x-1.0))
    return f

#the actual function calculating
def dH_dt(H, t=0):
    return np.array([c0*(H[1]-H[0]-f(H[0])),
                  c1*(H[0]-H[1]+H[2]),
                  -c2*H[1]])



#computational time steps
t = np.linspace(0, 30, 1000)
#x, y, and z initial conditions
H0 = [0.7, 0.0, 0.0]

H, infodict = integrate.odeint(dH_dt, H0, t, full_output=True)

print infodict['message']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(H[:,0], H[:,1], H[:,2])
plt.show()
```

Which gives me this:

[image]